# SharePoint 2013 - Deciding a Document Template Under Advance Settings of a Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, I am creating  a custom content type that will be associated to a custom master page for publishing pages.

After my content type is created, and I go into it's advance settings, there is option to "specify the document template for this content type."  Does it mater what this URL path should be for my publishing pages?  Or should this value be a specific SharePoint OOTB URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own path.  I don't know whether there are limitations on whether it has to be in the same library or the same site. I usually put mine in the document library's forms folder so they're hidden from users.